# How can i use the PasswordCredential API from Chrome in Angular 7

Tags: angular, google-chrome

i m making an App with Angular 7 and i want to store the password of the users in the chrome built in a link! and i cant use it because cant create the " new  PasswordCredential ".

i can check if it is availbe using '(window as any).PasswordCredential', but i cant create the instance of PasswordCredential

```
         if ((window as any).PasswordCredential) {
              const credentials = new PasswordCredential ({
                name: userLogin.username,
                password: userLogin.password,
              });
              return navigator.credentials.store(credentials);
            }
```

the error shows 'Cannot find name 'PasswordCredential'.ts(2304)'

and in the navigator also show 'Property 'credentials' does not exist on type 'Navigator'.ts(2339)'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to write:

```
    declare global {
     interface Window {
      PasswordCredential: any;
      FederatedCredential: any;
     }
    }
```

Then:

```
if (window.PasswordCredential) {
      ...your code here
    }
```